# SQL Geography Polygon lat longs exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, geospatial, spatial-query

I am trying to parse an xml file which contains spatial references and I've come to a standstill when trying to create the following polygon.

To try and overcome this I have been using SSMS to try and debug my problem.

I am using SQL 2012 Express.

XML Source Data

```
<Polygon>
    <Position latitude="-62" longitude="-114" />
    <Position latitude="34" longitude="-114" />
    <Position latitude="34" longitude="62" />
    <Position latitude="-62" longitude="62" />
    <Position latitude="-62" longitude="-114" />
</Polygon>
```

SQL Query

```
DECLARE @geom geography

SELECT @geom = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((
-62 -114,
34 -114,
34 62,
-62 62,
-62 -114
    ))',4326)
```

SQL Exception

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate     "geography": 
System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.
```

Thanks very much for any info
Adam

Comment: Are you sure latitude is the first value in a point? It could be longitude first.

Comment: Geography points take their input in (X,Y) format. Which for Lat,Longs is (Long, Lat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. I was inputting these in the wrong order.

Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsofts sample code the order is obviously longitude, latitude, while you exchanged that.